# Fails to use Azure caching in my web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-caching

In my webpage, which should display a gridview with table records, I've tried to add a cache so the grid will get the records from the cache, if exists, and if not will go to the DB itself.

Though when I load the page I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here's my code, I'll be glad to recieve any possible help:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (Page.IsPostBack)
            DataCache cache = new DataCache("default");
            DataSet result = (DataSet) cache.Get("table");
            if (result == null)
            {
                string connString = SqlAzureDataSource.ConnectionString;
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", connString);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                cache.Put("table", ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = result;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the problem locally on your machine or in the cloud ?

Comment: Assume you have a reference of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime attached to your project ? and it is the correct version ?

Comment: @JamesKn It doesn't work in the cloud, and I do have ServiceRuntime attached to my project...version 1.8.0.0

Comment: I think you just need to make sure you reference the 2.0.0.0 version to solve this issue. I am guess that your deployment project is set to the latest SDK but you are referencing in your project old SDKs. You can maybe set the ServiceRuntime to set Copy Local to true. But I think the best option is to use the latest 2.0.0.0 reference instead of 1.8.0.0 in your web project.

Comment: @JamesKn how can I update the reference?

Comment: Delete the current reference in your project and then just click Add Reference and select the right version from the list in .NET . (Assume you are using VS) Like you would do with normal reference in visual studio.

Comment: @JamesKn I only have 1.8.0.0 in that list

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/

Comment: You should be able to get hold of the latest SDK there but did you try the Copy Local True in your project ? Did that work?

Comment: @JamesKn Now I recieved Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified....what now :(??

Comment: Did you install the new SDK?

Comment: Delete the current reference in your project and then just click Add Reference and select the right version from the list in .NET . (Assume you are using VS) Like you would do with normal reference in visual studio.??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29903/discussion-between-user1067083-and-jameskn)